# Let TortoiseSVN ask for certificate

Tags: https, tortoisesvn

Until now I'm using SmartSVN to access our https-protected repository smoothly. SmartSVN simply asked for my certificate and the passphrase and was happy.

Now I want automatic update and commit and hence try **EasySVN** which is a TortoiseSVN-derivate. Unfortunately, it does not ask me for my credentials and just fails with "No certificates available".

When I try to perform an update on command line SVN, it asks me for the certificate and passphrase (why TortoiseSVN can't do that?), but fails:

```
E:\test>svn update
Updating '.':
Authentication realm: https://ourserver:8888
Client certificate filename: e:\path\to\my\certificate.p12
svn: E175002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://ourserver:8888/svn/my/checked/out/path'
svn: E175002: OPTIONS of 'https://ourserver:8888/svn/my/checked/out/path': SSL handshake failed: Secure connection truncated (https://ourserver:8888)
```

Comment: so, it works with that cert and passphrase in SmartSVN, but not via command line or EasySVN?

Answer (score 1):

This [page](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html#tsvn-dug-general-auth) tells you where to store a cert for TortoiseSVN, but it seems there's an issue with this in EasySVN, there's a ticket [here](https://public.assembla.com/spaces/easysvn-tortoise/tickets/105?comment=71423613) (hasn't been updated in a while though)